# How to add a prefix with folder name in adf?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have added a prefix('**machine**') with folder names using `@concat` earlier in ADF Copy Sink.

```
@concat('machine',substring(item().name,19,4))
```

Now I am using `split()` to take folder name using:

`@split(string(item().name),'_')[2]`

But I want to add a prefix('**machine**') just like I did earlier using `@concat` which is not working.

I tried: `@concat('m',split(string(item().name),'_')[2])`

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Cannot fit unknown into Function parameter.

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot fit unknown into Function parameter

[image]

- This is not the actual error.  You will get this error message in expression builder.
- You can ignore this error message and debug the pipeline. It will run successfully without the error message.